# React Native button onPressOut function call after 250 ms

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working with a React Native button in which i am calling a function. But i want to call the function only after 250 ms and when the user leaves the button which means when the onPressOut is called. How can i do that. Currently it's like this:

```js
const onChangeCurtain = () =>{
      setActive(!active);
      onPressItem();
}
const onLongPress = () => {
      setActive(false);
}

return (
  <Container
       onPress={onChangeCurtain}
       onPressOut={onLongPress}
  />
)
```

Now `onChangeCurtain` gets called immediately and `onLongPress` gets called when the user leaves the button. But i don't want `onLongPress` to be called if pressed for less than 250 ms. It should be called only if it gets pressed for more than 250 ms. How can i do that?

Comment: use event listener on `keyUp` and `keyDown`. in `keyDown` save time in which it was pressed and in `keyUp` compare previous time with current. If it is longer that 250ms then call your function.

Comment: It's actually in React Native. I just updated. @ciekals11

Comment: Have you tried using delayLongPress={250}?

Answer (score 0):

You can use event listeners on `button` like `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp`.

In `onKeyDown` start `setTimeout` which will perform something after 250ms
And in `onKeyUp` clear this interval so it will not trigger if user did not pressed guver button long enough.

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  let downTimer = null;

  const onMouseDown = () => {
    clearTimeout(downTimer);
    downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Mouse down > 250 ms');   
    }, 250);
  }

  const onMouseUp = () => {
    clearTimeout(downTimer);
  }

  return (
    <button onMouseUp={ onMouseUp } onMouseDown={ onMouseDown }>asd</button>
  );
}
```